# PHPMYADMIN Enum error1064

Tags: enums, phpmyadmin

enum error 1064 :

Got an error message when entering ENUM values to a field of a table in PHPMYADMIN......

Server version: 5.7.14 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Version information: 4.6.4

error 1064 : [image]

Answer (score 0):

Your phpMyAdmin version is quite old, I really suggest you upgrade. Indeed, I suspect you are experiencing a [bug](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/12480) that was [fixed](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/files/4.6.5/) in version [4.6.5](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/history/blob/master/ChangeLogs/ChangeLog-2016).

The current version is 5.0, which requires PHP 7.1 or newer and MySQL/MariaDB 5.5 or newer. If your PHP is older, the phpMyAdmin 4.9 release (currently 4.9.7) is still receiving security fixes and is compatible with PHP versions from 5.5 through 7.4. More information about version compatibility is available on the [phpMyAdmin download page](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/).